# Can anyone provide a good info on the various uses of hash(#) in urls?

Tags: http, url, web, uri

I'm developing a software, which is going to provide in-deep information about url's. 
While the get-params are simple, I'm having trouble with the hash.

At first it was used to mark places in the document to navigate to, but we're past that now. I've seen JS engines using it to store params similar to the get strings.

So, here's my question: is everything that comes after a hash free game, or are there any conventions about what it should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these sites it could help. [Fragment Identifier, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) or  [Pound Sign, Google](http://support.google.com/richmedia/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=190941)

It's got a list of examples you could use.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you need. Hashes are used in modern web applications that make use of asynchronous calls to the server using ajax. This e.g. allows the user to copy the link and receive the same content after pasting (actions taken are put into hash which changes the url which otherwise would remain static).

Answer (score 1):

You want to read http://www.jenitennison.com/blog/node/154

Comment: That blog post is now located at https://www.jenitennison.com/2011/03/06/hash-uris.html - but the author advises looking at an archived copy of the original instead, like https://web.archive.org/web/20120120032924/http://www.jenitennison.com/blog/node/154

Comment: Another copy can be found at https://www.w3.org/blog/2011/hash-uris/